# Hide empty column from datatable in html

Tags: html, datatable, datatables

I created a datatable with search feature enabled. In below code, if I search for "office" it returns two rows and the age column doesn't have any value in it, so I want to hide it. It should hide only when there is no data in all the rows in a column.

I've researched this question and have no idea of how to hide cells with no data in a column.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#example").DataTable({
            buttons: ["columnsToggle"],
            hideEmptyCols: true,
        });
    });
</script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fiona Green</td>
            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>55</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Added

```
hideEmptyCols: true
```

but it has no effect on this. I was expecting any column after searching/filter has no value that column should be hidden.

I will have multiple columns in this table but after putting a filter, it should hide all the columns that do not have any value in a particular column. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Are you including a script to enable this functionality? You don't state it in your code and it's not a built-in feature of DataTables. A quick search indicates that there are a few examples floating around, but they are a few years old and since I don't have any experience I'm not going to link them here. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74870495/edit) your question to show which example(s) you have tried and any success / failure.

Comment: @mark_b, yes I have included it in the script, but still it doesn't work. I searched everywhere and couldn't find anything similar.